# How to maintain controls through ViewState

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

On my initial pageload I'm trying to add a bunch of textboxes.  What I want to do is if a user types something into those text boxes I want to maintain that text.  I'm using a placeholder and placing dynamic controls inside of my placeholder.  Whenever the page_loads the ViewState is null.   I'm sure i'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

`default.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"
ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlacerHolder" EnableViewState="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="_postbackButton" OnClick="_postbackButton_Click" Text="PostBack" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`Default.aspx.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["myPlaceHolder"] == null)
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            Label myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Text = i.ToString();

            myPlacerHolder.Controls.Add(myLabel);

            TextBox rtb = new TextBox();
            rtb.ID = i.ToString() + "_TextBox";
            rtb.Width = 200;

            myPlacerHolder.Controls.Add(rtb);

            myPlacerHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal() { ID = i.ToString() + "row", Text = "<br/>" });



        }

    else
        myPlacerHolder = (PlaceHolder)ViewState["myPlaceHolder"];

    if (ViewState["myPlaceHolder"] == null)
        ViewState["myPlaceHolder"] = myPlacerHolder;



}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void _postbackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do nothing just cause postback
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. Assigning a control to the variable `myPlacerHolder` doesn't put that control in the page. The control remains in the page, and the variable has a reference to a control that is not in the page.
2. You can't reuse controls created for one page in another page.

Just recreate the `TextBox` controls each time the page loads, and they will pick up the entered text from the form data that is posted back to the server.